# PL/SQL looping 'back' through the records

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, hierarchical-data, oracleforms

I have a problem i hope you can help to resolve.

I have a table named PRODUCT:

```
Product_ID               NOT NULL NUMBER(10)       
TARGET_PRODUCT                    VARCHAR2(10)  
SOURCE_PRODUCT                    VARCHAR2(10)
```

So each target_product made out of source_product(except the first one - first one just has target_product and source_product is null)
I need to find the fist source_product for given target_product.
I need to go 'back' in a loop until source product is null.
Is there a solution for this scenario?

Thanks in advance

Comment: please share sample data and explain the question through desired output in order to reply your question in a concrete manner.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a *loop* you need, but *hierarchical query*. Have a look at the following example based on Scott's `EMP` table.

This is its contents; employees are displayed hierarchically, showing who's whose boss:

```
SQL> select level,
  2         lpad(' ', level * 2, ' ') || e.ename name
  3  from emp e
  4  start with e.mgr is null
  5  connect by prior e.empno= e.mgr;

     LEVEL NAME
---------- ---------------
         1   KING
         2     JONES
         3       SCOTT
         4         ADAMS
         3       FORD
         4         SMITH
         2     BLAKE
         3       ALLEN
         3       WARD
         3       MARTIN
         3       TURNER
         3       JAMES
         2     CLARK
         3       MILLER

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

As you want to start from the *middle* of the table (for example, starting from `SMITH`), you'd "reverse" it:

```
SQL> select level lvl,
  2            lpad(' ', level * 2, ' ') || e.ename name
  3     from emp e
  4     start with e.ename = 'SMITH'
  5     connect by prior e.mgr= e.empno;

       LVL NAME
---------- ---------------
         1   SMITH
         2     FORD
         3       JONES
         4         KING

SQL>
```

Finally, using that query as a CTE (or a subquery, if your Forms version doesn't support CTEs), fetch the one whose name has the highest level:

```
SQL> with temp as
  2    (select level lvl,
  3            lpad(' ', level * 2, ' ') || e.ename name
  4     from emp e
  5     start with e.ename = 'SMITH'
  6     connect by prior e.mgr= e.empno
  7    )
  8  select trim(t.name) name
  9  from temp t
 10  where t.lvl = (select max(t1.lvl) from temp t1);

NAME
---------------
KING

SQL>
```

---

Or, even better, using `connect_by_isleaf`:

```
SQL> select e.ename name
  2  from emp e
  3  where connect_by_isleaf = 1
  4  start with e.ename = 'SMITH'
  5  connect by prior e.mgr= e.empno;

NAME
---------------
KING

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try this, it will return the base target_product for a given target_product:

```
select * from (
  select PRODUCT_ID, TARGET_PRODUCT, SOURCE_PRODUCT 
  from PRODUCT
  start with target_product = '<your target product>'
  connect by prior SOURCE_PRODUCT = TARGET_PRODUCT
)
where SOURCE_PRODUCT is null;
```